# Why doesn't my function appear in the On Click field in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote a simple script for the button and threw it in the" On Click " in the button, but my Button1 function is not displayed there. How to solve this problem?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Nikita : MonoBehaviour
{
public void Button1()
{
    Debug.Log("button clicked");
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("started");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}  
}
```

Comment: Did you set to call Button1() in the onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

you want to set the button by:  public Button ButtonName;

then in start you want to add listener: ButtonName.onClick.AddListener(ButtonFunction);

then add button function :void ButtonFunction()
{

```
          Debug.Log("string here")
    }
```

then you just drag the button to the inspector, set the onclick in inspector and the option would be under the name Nikita-ButtonName

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html)

"Event System exists in the Scene to allow click detection" as adviced in the docs.
You can check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2018.4/ScriptReference/UI.Button.OnPointerClick.html) example.

For your case could be something like (not debugged):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Nikita : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("button clicked");
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("started");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }  
}
```